# Set a mode of a file in SQLite PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Is it possible to explicitly set a mode of a file which will be created by SQLite PDO constructor if it doesn't exists?
It's possible in [sqlite_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php) function and in [SQLiteDatabase::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php). What about PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that through PDO.

What you can do is `chmod()` the database file after it is created.

Comment: OK, thank you, I already have done it, but it's a bit ugly, and I tried to find a better solution =)